# Understanding the hint of a question to show that $G$ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Here is the question I want to answer:

Let $G$ be a finite group such that 3 does not divide $|G|$ and such that the identity $(xy)^3 = x^3 y^3$ holds for all $x,y \in G.$ Show that $G$ is abelian.

And here is the hint I got for the question:

First show that the map $G \rightarrow G$ given by $x \mapsto x^3$ is bijective. Then show that $x^2 \in Z(G)$ for all $x \in G.$

**My questions are:**

1- Could anyone explain for me why we should show that the map $G \rightarrow G$ given by $x \mapsto x^3$ is bijective?

2- Also, why we should show that $x^2 \in Z(G)$ for all $x \in G$?

3- And how proving the hint will show that $G$ is Abelian?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: After proving Hint 1, you could prove Hint 2 by showing that $x^2y^3=yxyxy=y^3x^2$ for all $x,y \in G$. Then you could use this and  the fact that $x^2y^2 = yxyx$ to prove that $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @Shaun  I am sorry, I will edit my title.

Comment: @DerekHolt I think the first hint proof is very trivial .... correct?

Comment: @DerekHolt when will I use Hint 1?

Comment: When will I use the given that there is no element in $G$ with order 3?

Comment: You use the fact that $G$ has no element of order 3 to prove Hint 1. (I assumed you had already done that.) You use Hint 1 to prove Hint 2. Try and do it yourself now.